# Installing SDL web 8 in a load balancing environment

Tags: web8

We have requirement of installing Web 8 on two virtual server using shared CM and Topology Manager database.While installing Web8 we need to provide Content Manager Webroot URL for Topology Manager CM Environment.What should be the URL in this case??

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you have scaled out CM servers, you should configure the URL of your CM load balancer in the Content Manager Webroot URL (i.e. the "public" URL of your CM website).

It is also important that all CM servers have the same Environment ID. By default, the Environment ID is derived from your Database (server) name, which automatically means that the Environment ID is the same for all CM servers (since they share the same database).

Comment: BTW: The CM Webroot URL you enter in the installer is stored in Topology Manager (it's a property of a `CmEnvironment` in Topology Manager). You can change it in Topology Manager after installation, if needed.